# How do I implement something like a logger correctly in python?

Tags: python, debugging, logging

In order to be able to debug a simple python network application, I'd like to write all requests and responses received to a file.

If done in an object oriented way it would be reasonable to put this logging functionality into a single instance that gets used throughout the application. And for efficiency it would be reasonable to not open, write and close a file every time some log message arrives. Instead opening it on construction of such a logging object and closing the file stream on destruction would be reasonable.

It seems that python does not give good control about the destruction process. Therefor just closing such a log file on destruction of some kind of logging object seems to be dangerous. Using the typical "with" statement is impossible as well because such a logging object needs to be completely independent from the control flow. My question is: How can I implement such a logging thing in python, where I can pass such a logger freely around and the log file will automatically get closed if the program terminates for some reason?

Comment: Check out the `logging` module that is distributed with Python. It will manage log levels, formatting, file handling, etc. for you. you can also pass the logger object around your application. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: Thank you for this information. In my case this is some kind of ... misusing the logging infrastructure because I'd rather require writing out some binary data in a specific format. Nevertheless I like your suggestion though it has some drawbacks in my specific case. Thank you for that hint.